# Array remove object at: ? String may not be indexed with 'Int', it has variable size elements error

Tags: arrays, swift3

Hello i want to remove object from array in swift 3 gives me error

> String may not be indexed with 'Int', it has variable size elements error

My codes here

```
var itemListcomming = String()
itemListcomming = itemListcomming.remove(at: 16)
```

any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` in Swift 2 was a small pain to work with when it comes to indexing, even more so with Swift 3. You can't give an `Int` as the index but manipulate the`startIndex` / `endIndex` to get to the position you want. That has been true since Swift 1.0.

Anyhow, if you want to remove the 16th character of the string:

```
var itemListcomming = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
let index = itemListcomming.index(itemListcomming.startIndex, offsetBy: 16)
itemListcomming.remove(at: index)

print(itemListcomming)
```

Comment: would you mind to share where details like this are documented please? @CodeDifferent